# Preserving information in Redmine during SVN repository migration

Tags: svn, redmine

We use two SVN repositories for different sections of our code for historical reasons. I have been asked to move the contents of the repository where the code I work on resides, to a directory in the other repository. In addition, our svn repositories are linked to Redmine.

Is there a way to preserve the repository information in Redmine during this migration? For example, if I have a ticket which shows that r6939 was committed against it, is there a way to make it update to the new revision number after the migration?